# Tensorflow conv2d_transpose size error "Number of rows of out_backprop doesn't match computed"

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am creating a convolution autoencoder in tensorflow. I got this exact error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Conv2DBackpropInput: Number of rows of out_backprop doesn't match computed: actual = 8, computed = 12
     [[Node: conv2d_transpose = Conv2DBackpropInput[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](conv2d_transpose/output_shape, Variable_1/read, MaxPool_1)]]
```

Relevant code:

```
l1d = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(l1da, w2, [10, 12, 12, 32], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
```

where

```
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64], stddev=0.01))
```

I checked the shape of the input to conv2d_transpose i.e. l1da and it is correct(10x8x8x64). The batch size is 10, input to this layer is in the form of 8x8x64, and the output is supposed to be 12x12x32.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the error. Padding should be "Valid", not "Same".

Comment: Exact same question answered in detail here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488717/confused-about-conv2d-transpose?noredirect=1&lq=1