# Shapes are not compatible in TF during gradient computation of MaxPoolWithArgmax

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I've tried to build a rather special network in TensorFlow and I kinda got it to work. Sadly, I stumbled upon an error that I am not able to fix or even find the right place to start with.
As far as I can tell the network is built successfully until the loss function is defined. The error message then says something about uncompatible shapes:

`ValueError: Shapes (1, 17, 17, 44) and (1, 16, 16, 44) are not compatible`

The thing is the error does not say at which tensor or line of code the problem occurs. I've printed all shapes that I could come up with and I can't even find something of the shape (1, 17, 17, 44).

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_nn_ops
@ops.RegisterGradient("MaxPoolWithArgmax")
def _MaxPoolWithArgmaxGrad(op, grad, some_other_arg):
  return gen_nn_ops._max_pool_grad(op.inputs[0],
                                   op.outputs[0],
                                   grad,
                                   op.get_attr("ksize"),
                                   op.get_attr("strides"),
                                   padding=op.get_attr("padding"),
                                   data_format='NHWC')
class FCN_RGBD:

    def __init__(self, checkpoint_dir='./checkpoints/'):
        self.build(1)

        # "allow_soft_placement = True" makes TensorFlow automatically choose an existing and supported GPU device
        self.config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement = True)
        self.session = tf.Session(config = self.config)
        self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    def weight_variable(self, shape):
        initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
        return tf.Variable(initial)

    def bias_variable(self, shape):
        initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
        return tf.Variable(initial)

    def conv_layer(self, x, W_shape, b_shape, strides, name, padding):
        W = self.weight_variable(W_shape)
        b = self.bias_variable([b_shape])
        return tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=strides, padding=padding) + b)

    def conv_skip_layer(self, x, W_shape, b_shape, name, padding):
        W = self.weight_variable(W_shape)
        b = self.bias_variable([b_shape])
        return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding=padding) + b

    def deconv_layer(self, x, out_shape, W_shape, b_shape, strides, name, padding):
        W = self.weight_variable(W_shape)
        b = self.bias_variable([b_shape])
        return tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, W, output_shape=out_shape, strides=strides, padding=padding) + b

    def pool_layer3x3(self, x):
        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            return tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(x, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 3, 3, 1], padding='SAME')

    def pool_layer2x2(self, x):
        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            return tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    def build(self, batchsize):

        print('Building the FCN...')

        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):

            self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batchsize, 250, 250, 1))
            self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(batchsize, 250, 250, 1))

            self.rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])

            conv1 = self.conv_layer(self.x, [5, 5, 1, 64], 64, [1, 2, 2, 1], 'conv1', 'SAME')

            pool1, pool_1_argmax = self.pool_layer3x3(conv1)

            conv1_skip = self.conv_skip_layer(pool1, [1, 1, 64, 44], 44, 'conv1_skip', 'VALID')

            conv2 = self.conv_layer(pool1, [3, 3, 64, 128], 128, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'conv2', 'VALID') 

            pool2, pool_2_argmax = self.pool_layer2x2(conv2)

            conv2_skip = self.conv_skip_layer(pool2, [1, 1, 128, 44], 44, 'conv2_skip', 'VALID')

            conv3 = self.conv_layer(pool2, [5, 5, 128, 256], 256, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'conv3', 'VALID')

            conv4 = self.conv_layer(conv3, [3, 3, 256, 44], 44, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'conv4', 'SAME')

            deconv1 = self.deconv_layer(conv4, tf.stack([batchsize, 16, 16, 44]), [3, 3, 44, 44], 44, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'deconv1', 'SAME')

            conv2_skip = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(conv2_skip, 16, 16)

            sum1 = conv2_skip + deconv1

            dropout1 = tf.nn.dropout(sum1, keep_prob=0.5)

            deconv2 = self.deconv_layer(dropout1, tf.stack([batchsize, 34, 34, 44]), [4, 4, 44, 44], 44, [1, 2, 2, 1], 'deconv2', 'SAME')

            conv1_skip = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(conv1_skip, 34, 34)

            sum2 = conv1_skip + deconv2

            dropout2 = tf.nn.dropout(sum2, keep_prob=0.5)

            deconv_final = self.deconv_layer(dropout2, tf.stack([batchsize, 250, 250, 44]), [19, 19, 44, 44], 44, [1, 7, 7, 1], 'deconv_final', 'VALID')

            annotation_pred = tf.argmax(deconv_final, dimension=3, name='prediction')

            cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.squeeze(self.y, squeeze_dims=[3]), logits=deconv_final)

            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy_mean')

            self.train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.rate).minimize(self.loss)

            self.prediction = tf.argmax(tf.reshape(tf.nn.softmax(logits), tf.shape(deconv_final)), dimension=3)
```

And this is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 560, in merge_with
    new_dims.append(dim.merge_with(other[i]))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 135, in merge_with
    self.assert_is_compatible_with(other)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 108, in assert_is_compatible_with
    % (self, other))
ValueError: Dimensions 17 and 16 are not compatible

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    fcn_rgbd = FCN_RGBD()
  File "C:\Users\user\netcase\Workspace\Depth_BPC_v1\FCN_RGBD.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.build(1)
  File "C:\Users\user\netcase\Workspace\Depth_BPC_v1\FCN_RGBD.py", line 162, in build
    self.train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.rate).minimize(self.loss)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py", line 315, in minimize
    grad_loss=grad_loss)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py", line 386, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py", line 580, in gradients
    in_grad.set_shape(t_in.get_shape())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 413, in set_shape
    self._shape = self._shape.merge_with(shape)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 564, in merge_with
    (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (1, 17, 17, 44) and (1, 16, 16, 44) are not compatible
```

I am very sorry for this vaguely described problem, but I really don’t have a notion where to start.

Comment: why do you define your own gradient? I would guess this is the source of an error, as exception is thrown during gradient computation.

Comment: Because there is no gradient atm for MaxPoolWithArgmax as far as I know (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1793). But I've tried the same with 'normal' max_pool and I've got the same error.

Comment: are you sure there is the same error **in a clean run** without it? (people sometimes just comment out the line in notebook, which does not remove registered gradient from memory). Since the error is purely in gradient computation, if this is not related to your overwrite than it would look like a bug in tf, which is not very probable.

Comment: Yes, sadly thats not it. I do not use a notebook and tried it several times, same error.

Comment: I've got the feeling the deconvolution function might be the source of evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem of wrong dimensions in different layers. Unfortunately, the error messages for conv2d_transpose are not very helpful. This posting helped me a lot: [Confused about conv2d_transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488717/confused-about-conv2d-transpose)

Comment: Quite interesting it did not raise any errors during network construction though. Is this due to some broadcasting involved?

Comment: I wouldn't know, but I believe the answer is no. Thank you anyways! :)