# tf.nn.conv2d_transpose gives InvalidArgumentError: Conv2DCustomBackpropInput: input and filter must have the same depth

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution, deconvolution

I'm facing issues with getting `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` to work correctly. Here is a small reproduction of what I'm trying to do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Shape (2, 3, 3, 1) == (batch_sz, height, width, channels)
inp = tf.Variable(np.array(
    [
        [
            [[1], [2], [3]],
            [[2], [3], [4]],
            [[7], [8], [9]]
        ],
        [
            [[3], [2], [1]],
            [[2], [7], [2]],
            [[3], [2], [0]]
        ]
    ], dtype = np.float32
))
# Shape (5, 5, 3, 1) == (kH, kW, out_channels, in_channels)
ker = tf.Variable(np.array(
    [
        [[[1],[2],[1]], [[2],[2],[2]], [[1],[2],[1]], [[2],[1],[1]], [[1],[1],[1]]],
        [[[1],[2],[1]], [[2],[2],[2]], [[1],[2],[1]], [[2],[1],[1]], [[1],[1],[1]]],
        [[[1],[2],[1]], [[2],[2],[2]], [[1],[2],[1]], [[2],[1],[1]], [[1],[1],[1]]],
        [[[1],[2],[1]], [[2],[2],[2]], [[1],[2],[1]], [[2],[1],[1]], [[1],[1],[1]]],
        [[[1],[2],[1]], [[2],[2],[2]], [[1],[2],[1]], [[2],[1],[1]], [[1],[1],[1]]]
    ], dtype = np.float32
))
out = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(inp, ker, (2, 7, 7, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1), padding='SAME', data_format='NHWC', name='conv_transpose')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output, kernel, input = sess.run([out, ker, inp])
```

What I want is to perform a transposed convolution on a 3x3x1 input using three 5x5x1 filters. I expect the output to be of shape 7x7x3 - but instead, I get an error saying:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Conv2DCustomBackpropInput: input and filter must have the same depth
     [[Node: conv_transpose_2 = Conv2DBackpropInput[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](conv_transpose_2/output_shape, Variable_21/read, Variable_20/read)]]
```

Aren't the input and filter depth both equal to 1? I don't see what I'm doing wrong - any hints would be really appreciated. I specifically want to use `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` and not `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose`.

Comment: Have you expanded the 0'th and 3'th dimension of your arrarys?

Comment: Sorry for sounding like a noob. No, I have not. Why would I need to do that? Are my arrays not already in the format required by conv2d_transpose - [batches, in_height, in_width, channels] for input and [filter_height, filter_width, out_channels, in_channels] for the filters --> Docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose

Answer (score 0):

This issue is similar to this [Stack Overflow Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488717/confused-about-conv2d-transpose).

You should do the below changes for your code to run.

1. Shape of `inp` should be (2, 3, 3, 3) instead of (2, 3, 3, 1)
2. Shape of `ker` should be (5,5,1,3) instead of (5,5,3,1)
3. Padding should be set to 'VALID' instead of 'SAME' only then `Output Shape` will be different from `Input Shape`.

Mentioned below is the working code (did it with zeroes for ease of implementation):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Shape (2, 3, 3, 3) == (batch_sz, height, width, channels)
inp = tf.Variable(np.array(np.zeros((2, 3, 3, 3)) , dtype = np.float32))

# Shape (5, 5, 3, 1) == (kH, kW, out_channels, in_channels)
ker = tf.Variable(np.zeros((5,5,1,3)) , dtype = np.float32)

out = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value = inp, filter = ker, output_shape=(2, 7, 7, 1), 
                             strides=(1, 1, 1, 1), padding='VALID', data_format='NHWC', name='conv_transpose')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output, kernel, input = sess.run([out, ker, inp])
```